# Why are gasoline prices so hugely different between America and Europe?

Tags: united-states, markets, commodities, european-union

I noticed in several cases it's triple or more.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tax. In the UK, for example, over 60% of the price is tax.

Comment: Wheras in the US it usually runs at less than 25% sometimes substantially less.